# Emailing unique code to user

Tags: php, email, unique-key

I'm really stumped, and I hope someone can help me: I have a list of pre-generated promotional codes. Everytime a user enter his email in a form, I want to generate an email containing one of the predefined codes – and obviously, each code should only be sent once.

I know how to send and generate emails, and if I could just generate a code on the fly, I would also know how do that. But I've never tried to 'grab' one code at a time, one after the other, using php.

So any help is appreciated!

Comment: any code? tried something?

Comment: Where are the promo codes stored? In a text file? A series of text files? A database?

Comment: Right now, I have the in an Excel file. But I imagine I'll put them in a mysql database.

Comment: Well, than it is just getting a random number out of the database that doesn't have a flag of `used` on it. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Insert all your codes in the database with a column named "sent" and a unique ID (with auto_increment).

Then get a code with

```
SELECT id,code FROM my_codes WHERE sent = 0 LIMIT 1;
```

Send the code and safe that you've used the code with:

```
UPDATE my_codes SET sent = 1 WHERE id = $the_id_from_the_selected_code;
```

If you don't want to use the code again you can just delete the code without using a sent column.

```
DELETE FROM my_codes WHERE id = $the_id_from_the_selected_code;
```

To generate a unique code "on the fly" you can just use `uniqid(rand())`, which returns a uniq ID based on the time in microseconds and a random prefix for the case that 2 mails will be generated at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do something like this:

```
| id (INT (11)) | coupon_code (varchar(30)) | sent_status (INT (11)) | date |
```

=============================================================================

```
SELECT * FROM coupon_code WHERE sent_status=0 ORDER BY RAND( ) // use this during sending email

$coupon_code = $row["coupon_code"];

UPDATE coupon_code SET sent_status='1' where coupon_code='$coupon_code'; // update coupon_code table once you get the code and after sending email to user.
```